# using foreach in onSaveInstanceState throws nullpointerexception

Tags: android, foreach, constants, fragment

I am trying to save the tags for all fragments in an activity that are currently visible.

So I defined these:

```
// Fragment TAGS
private final static String EDIT_COLLECTIONS_TAG = "edit collection";
public final static String EDIT_IMAGE_TAG = "edit image";
public final static String ADD_IMAGE_TAG = "add image";

// Collection of Frag Tags
private final static String[] FRAG_TAGS = {EDIT_COLLECTIONS_TAG, EDIT_IMAGE_TAG, ADD_IMAGE_TAG};
```

And in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` I did:

```
    for(String tag : FRAG_TAGS){
        if(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag).isVisible()){
            outState.putString(tag, tag);
        }           
    }
```

...but LogCat informed me that the `if` line was throwing the null pointer exception.

So not knowing why I tried:

```
    if(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAG_TAGS[1]).isVisible()){
        outState.putString(EDIT_IMAGE_TAG, EDIT_IMAGE_TAG);
    }
```

...and that worked.

So it seems there isn't a problem with accessing the array. On a lark I changed the array's contents to actually strings: `{"EDIT_COLLECTIONS_TAG", "EDIT_IMAGE_TAG", "ADD_IMAGE_TAG"}` but that didn't change the outcome.

So what's going on here?

Comment: Maybe you could use the debugger to go through your code step-by-step and discover at runtime what the values of your variables are. You might have to define them first.

Comment: And what happens if you don't find fragment? It is going to be null, and you can't call .isVisible() on Null Object. For each is working for sure so don't bother with that.

Comment: What Marko said. See where you hardcoded the index?  Try hardcoding each index and finding which tag leads to a fragment that could not be resolved.  foreach works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the input by Marko Lazic I discovered two errors:

1. Not all added fragments were given tags, this resulted in nulls. This has been rectified.
2. Cannot use a static list of all fragment tags because, obviously, some will not have been added yet and as Marko indicated, can't find a fragment that isn't there yet, so this was also throwing null.

Solution:

1. I needed to find a way to create a dynamic list of tags for added fragments. This was accomplished with:

   ```
   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
   @Override
   public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
     super.onAttachFragment(fragment);

     // add attached fragment's tag to set of tags for attached fragments
     AddedFragmentTagsSet.add(fragment.getTag());

     // if when adding the fragment another fragment has become detached, remove its tag from the set
     for(String tag : AddedFragmentTagsSet){
       if(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag).isDetached()){ // or isVisible() probably
           AddedFragmentTagsSet.remove(tag);
       }
       Log.d(TAG, SCOPE +"contents of AddedFragmentTagsSet: " +tag);
     }
   }
   ```

Thank your for the help, folks.